# Equilibrium Index Implementation

Tags: functional-programming, scala

I have come up with a solution to the [equilibrium index problem](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Equilibrium_index) with help from the answers off [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31462542/return-a-stream-filtered-by-a-predicate-from-a-zipper):

```
val in = Stream(-7, 1, 5, 2, -4, 3, 0)
val sum = in.scan(0)(_ + _)
val hash = (in zip sum) map { case (e, lsum) => 2*lsum + e }
val target = sum.last
hash.zipWithIndex.collect { case (e, i) if e == target => i }
```

It's unfortunate that I have to traverse through the whole stream again to get `target`.

Are there any possible improvements?

Answer (score 1):

`hash` is poorly named, I think, but that's a minor detail.

Your solution is inefficient because you are doing it all with sequences.  Have you considered that `zipWithIndex` is *also* duplication?  You've already worked through the input stream once - each time you calculated the current sum, you *could* (had you wanted) have been aware of your position in the list?  You're duplicating work.

More efficient solution (in that there will only be one traversal) is to **fold**, not **scan** and to build a map (for quick extraction of results).

Fold over the input stream, with a seed of (0, 0, Map[Int, List[Int]]).  The first value is an index accumulator, the second is a sum accumulator and the nature of the map will become obvious shortly.  The function you apply to each fold iteration should

1. Add the current stream item to twice the accumulated sum.
2. If the resulting number **is not** a key in the map, insert `list(index-accumulator-value)' into the map with that newly-calculated number as a key
3. If the resulting number **is** already a key, add index-accumulator-value to the list stored under that key (important: **cons** it to the list, do not append).
4. Increment the index accumulator by one.
5. Add the current stream item to the accumulated sum.
6. Return `(index-accumulator, sum-accumulator, map)`

Once the fold has completed, you will have

1. The size of the stream (which you don't need)
2. The sum of the stream (which you do)
3. A map.

If the map contains a key which is equal to the sum of the stream, the value associated with that key will be a list of all equilibrium indices, sorted in reverse order.  If there is no such key, there were no equilibrium indices.

- Minimal traversal
- No filtering necessary
- Rapid access to final result because Map

Done.

Annoyed that the final result is in reverse order?  Reversing one final list is cheap compared to appending to each list in the map, every time.

Note that you can dispense with having to manage the index-accumulator by folding over `in.zipWithIndex`